On the IVP $\frac{dy}{dx} = x^2 + e^{-y^2}, \quad y(0) = 0. $
Using Picard's Existence and Uniqueness Theorem, find the largest interval of existence and uniqueness  of the solution for the initial value problem (IVP): $$
\frac{dy}{dx} = x^2 + e^{-y^2}, \quad y(0) = 0.
$$
I tried as below
To determine the interval of uniqueness for the solution of the IVP
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = x^2 + e^{-y^2}, \quad y(0) = 0,
$$
Apply the Picard Existence and Uniqueness Theorem.

Identify ( f(x, y) ): The function here is $ f(x, y) = x^2 + e^{-y^2}$.

Checking Continuity of ( f(x, y) ): The function $ f(x, y) = x^2 + e^{-y^2} $ is continuous for all $ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 $, since both $ x^2 $ and $ e^{-y^2}$ are continuous in $ \mathbb{R} $.

Checking the Partial Derivative $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} $: We compute $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$:
$$
   \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{d}{dy} \left( x^2 + e^{-y^2} \right) = -2y e^{-y^2}.
   $$
This derivative is also continuous for all $ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Applying the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem: Since both $f(x, y) $ and $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ are continuous everywhere, the theorem guarantees that there is a unique solution to this IVP in a neighbourhood around $ x = 0 $ (the initial point). However, the theorem does not specify a global interval of uniqueness for solutions, only a local one.

Analyzing the Interval of Unique Solution: The interval of unique solution is given as $[-h, h]$, where $$h=  min (a, \frac{b}{1+a^2})= min (a, \frac{b}{M})$$ where we consider the rectangle $R: |x|\leq a, |y|\leq b $ around $(0,0)$ and $M= sup_{R}|f(x,y)|.$ Now I am stuck on how to find the value of $h. $ Please help. Thank you.


